# Converting UTS (UTC-0) times to BST in PHP or jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm pulling the most recent listened tracks from last.fm and putting them on my website.

Problem is, the times are retrieved in UTC-0 uts format and appear to be an hour out when comparing them to BST times in order to calculate a fuzzy time stamp ("about 5mins ago", "about an hour ago" etc).

Is there any way solve this so the times always match BST/GMT and adjust when entering and leaving daylight saving time?

Here's a snippet of PHP code i'm using at the moment, which results in the times being an hour out.

```
    $now = time();  // use this so all times are to the same second 
    $tz = getenv("TZ"); // save local setting so we can reset it later
    putenv("TZ=Europe/London"); 

    $trackPlayedAt = date('d M Y H:i:s', $track->date->uts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date()` automatically formats to the local timezone. The timezone depends on the configuration of the PHP server. If everything is set correctly, it should *just work*.

If you are running PHP 5.3 you have more options. Comment with which version of PHP you are running.

Comment: You're right! The script works fine on my hosting, but isn't working fine on my local MAMP setup. I'm not too sure how to configure it though :S

Comment: Cool. Yeah, dates can be funny if you try to hard. I decided years ago to just let `date()` do it's think. You can verify the timezone setting in your php.ini or run `phpinfo()`. You are probably just missing DST or something.